# Many to many data structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, routes

I have a bunch of routes in my small, frameless, single page application. I also have a bunch of events ready to get wired up. Some events are common and are on nearly every page. Some aren't.

What is a good method for cleanly, clearly triggering a cherry picked list of which events to run based on the route without having to duplicate event code?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish? And what do you mean by cherry-picked?

Comment: make events that raise several other events, then just use those group events mainly, and specific single calls when needed. much like adding class attribs to html tags to form groups...